# Does JVM starts when scala REPL is started

Tags: scala

I am new to scala.
I want to know if JVM is started when log into scala REPL
and JVM is stopped , when we exit the scala REPL.

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Scala is just a JVM / Java library. So yes, anytime scala runs, a JVM is spun up.

In case of the REPL, it starts and stop a JVM. You can confirm by doing a `jps` in another terminal when you start and stop the REPL.

Comment: Answer ignores scala-js and scala-native.

Comment: @som-snytt - new to scala and scala REPL notwithstanding?

Comment: "just a jvm library" is too strong. http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com/ for instance. That's the new newbie experience. "The command line REPL uses scalac running on the JVM" is currently true, AFAIK. Not to split hairs, just to say Scala is real on JS, and maybe one is only interested in that backend.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which implementation of Scala you are using. There are currently two production-ready stable implementations of Scala on different platforms, one in development, and two abandoned:

- Scala.NET (abandoned): there is no JVM involved at all
- Scala-LLVM (abandoned): there is no JVM involved at all
- Scala-native (in development): there is no JVM involved at all
- Scala.JS (production-ready): there is no JVM involved at all (unless you run it in Rhino, dyn.js, or Nashorn on top of a JVM)
- Scala-JVM: there is a JVM involved, but it doesn't necessarily have to be started or stopped when the REPL is started or stopped. It depends on the JVM. There are JVMs which cache and reuse running JVM instances instead of starting and stopping them. There are also Java Operating Systems, where the JVM is *always* running and never stopped.